# How to get item's position in a list of list?

Tags: python, list

I don't know how to get certain items' position in a list of list.

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

if I want to get the position of '4' in the list,
the result should be like this.

```
list[1][0]
```

Or other expressions .
Thank you

Comment: "if I want to get the position of '4' in the list, the result should be like this... Or other expressions . Thank you... "  Is that a question? I mean.. sorry I dont folow

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to ask how to index items from a matrix (2D list), then imagine your list like this.
    [a,b,c]

```
a = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
b = [ 4 , 5 , 6 ]
c = [ 7 , 8 , 9 ]
```

To access any number, you want to access the sublist it is in (ie a or b or c first then access which item this is in the sublist you have chosen).

Let's say I want the number four. Four is in the second list, which is one index away from the first index, so we access this entire list with `list[1]`. However, we want the first element of this list, which is zero elements away from the first element, so we would access this as a[0], but in this case a is list[1], so overall the statement you would want to write would be:

```
list[1][0]
```

Another example would be if you wanted to get the number 3. 3 is in the sublist  list[0], which we can imagine is named a, and if we wanted to access 3 from a we would type a[2]. However, in this case, we don't have a list 'a' but instead a list named list[0], so we would type:

```
list[0][2].
```

Hope this helps!

Update:

Here is a simple python solution. It checks if a four is in each sub-list in the matrix my_list.

```
for sub_list in my_list:
  if 4 in sub_list:
    print(my_list.index(sub_list),sub_list.index(4))
```

Comment: This is a nice explanation, but I believe you misunderstood the question. The OP is asking how to _find_ the index of a certain element in a 2D list 'programmaticlly'. _"I don't know how to **get certain items' position in a list of list**"_.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,l in enumerate(list):
    if 4 in l:
        print "list[" + i + "][" + l.index(4) + "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try the first list. If at first you don't succeed, try, try again:

```
def indices(xss,x):
    for i,xs in enumerate(xss):
        try:
            return i,xs.index(x)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    raise ValueError
```

For example,

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> indices(x,4)
(1, 0)
```

By the way -- you should avoid calling a list variable `list`, since that is the name of a built-in.